# Object storage: when to choose OpenStack (Swift) vs. Ceph

Tags: openstack, ceph

Swift (OpenStack) and Ceph are both open source projects that implement object storage.

What are the factors to consider when trying to decide which one to deploy? Under what scenarios would you choose Swift, and what scenarios would you choose Ceph?

Comment: Not a final answer to your question, but you might find this blog post helpfull in making your decision: http://www.mirantis.com/blog/object-storage-openstack-cloud-swift-ceph/

Answer (score 5):

Swift provides a scalable, highly available object store, that is available through a HTTP REST interface (only).

Ceph provides a scalable, consistent object store and a bunch of interfaces to access it, including native access, an http REST API, block devices and a filesystem-type interface.

Swift is more appropriate for storing objects that are independent of each other, since it does not guarantee consistency. Example: static content for a website (Wikipedia uses Swift).

Ceph is more appropriate for storing dependent objects such as virtual hard disks. Example: access to a block device or filesystem over the network for virtual machines.